# Ajax to navigate Json content from list page to details page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I use ajax to pull Json content from another site (Say: Site A). The and code is like below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://www.xxx.com",
    dataType: "json",
    success: processData,
    error: function(){ alert("failed"); }
});

function processData(data)
{
  console.log(data);
}
});
</script>
```

I managed to list the content. But this is a list page. I need to enable people to navigate to a details page. Which means when people click on a item, it sends request with parameters back to the other site (Site A), then get response with the content in details page. How can I do it under ajax? Hopes it makes sense. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your processData function should iterate through the items in the returned data list, render the html and add it to the DOM. You can use a library like moustache or knockout to do this. I believe there are also jQuery plugins that can help. Alternatively you can just create the html manually in your javascript.

Additionally you would need to attach a function to the click event of each of these items, which would perform a request in approximately the same manner as your existing code, but with the parameters added to the URL query string. The manner in which you do this would depend on how you render your html. The response can then be rendered in the DOM in a manner similar to how you would render the list, albeit for the whole JSON response.

Comment: How do I send request back with the codes like to above? I guess I can not add parameters to the URL query string. The above javascript actually also has got headers like this:

    headers : {
            "Accept-Datetime" :  "Fri, 15 Feb 2013 00:00:00 GMT",
            "Authorization" : "Basic asdsadsdsd",
        },

I also tried added parameters in the url like: /id=11&pirce=10000. It failed. I think I need to add parameters in the headers. But how do I send this request?

Comment: You probably need to ask the authors of the site how to do that. Adding parameters to a request is usually done by either adding them as a query string to the URL (easy), or as key/value pairs in the body of a POST request (harder). In both cases you would perform your request using $.ajax, as you've already done. You can also try to use Fiddler to see how that site is currently doing it.